# Setting upstream on a repo

Tags: git, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am trying to pull the `master` branch from a `remote` using `libgit2sharp`.

Sometimes I have to change the `remote` to a different url and pull from that `remote`.
When I change the `remote` and try to `pull` I get this error:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch
```

I know I have to do `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master` to fix this issue using git, but I wonder how can I do the same with `libgit2sharp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given mybranch, a `Branch` instance, which is already configured to track a branch in the `origin` remote.

If all you're willing to do is reconfigure the remote (while keeping the local and remote tracking branch configuration), to another one (eg. "myOtherRemote"), then the following piece of code should do the trick.

```
repo.Branches.Update(myBranch, b => b.Remote = "myOtherRemote");
```